# How to get taxonomy tree with path auto token?

Tags: 8, path-aliases, tokens

I'm using Path auto module to automatically set url of articles.
Last part of url is node title and `[node:title]` works just fine. But url part before node title should follow taxonomy structure (tree) of tag used for tagging that article (taxonomy name: "structural_category".

So i.e. if article is tagged with tag "Child" and that tag has parent tag called "Parent" then url of my article should be:

```
/parent/child/node-title
```

I can get only Child tag with tokens like this: `[node:field_structural_category:0]`, but I don't see the way to get Child's tag parent with token. With "Browse available tokens" I just can't drill any deeper than tag which is used directly for tagging the article.

For Drupal 7 I found that there is a solution with "join" keyword, something like:

```
[term:taxonomy_name:join:/]/[term:name]
```

[What are the URL Alias pattern replacements for taxonomy parent terms when building up Node paths?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75949/what-are-the-url-alias-pattern-replacements-for-taxonomy-parent-terms-when-build/75953#75953)

And I know that for Drupal 8 there should be something like:

```
[term:parent:url:path]/[term:name]
```

But when I try to save pattern like that I get an error "Path pattern is using the following invalid tokens:..."

When I use "Available tokens" helper tool I don't see this "term" at all?! All I see is:

[image: My available options]

There's no a word on "join", "parent" or any other similar token.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Token should look like:

```
[node:field_structural_category:entity:parents]
```

It appeared (I think) after I changed reference field from multiple to accept only one value.

While it was accepting multiple values I could access first 3 elements, but not their parents. So this option is available only for single value fields. I see that lot of tokens are missing when tag reference field is set to accept multiple values. Bug or feature - can't say.

Comment: Have you tried [node:field_structural_category:0:entity:parents] for the first term parents when multiple values are allowed? It seems it should follow that logic, just choose which delta if there are more than one.

Comment: Hmm..seems to work (I'm not getting error message for that construction) but it's not available in "Available tokens" helper pop-up.

Comment: Maybe it just needs to be added to the token suggestion list. I haven't been involved with this a lot, but maybe you can search the issues and see if anything similar is reported, or submit a new one?